Skip .app folders when using "fdupes" with the option "--recurse"
I am using fdupes to print the list of duplicate files in a certain folder, with the option --recurse.
However, since I am using macOS, the recursing process regards Mac apps (which appear to be folders ended with .app) as folders and runs into them, thus producing lots of unwanted extra information on duplicated files. Is there some way to skip such folders?

Does this answer your question? Exclude folder from deletions when finding duplicates with "fdupes"

@killertofus Thank you for the suggestion. But no, the linked question is concerned of preserving files from a preferred folder during deletion of duplicate files, while my question is to skip certain folders with some pattern(s) in the folders' name.

You might like to try jdupes which is similar to fdupes but provides an extra option to exclude files based on criteria including a string match to the full path:
-X nostr:.app/

It seems to be available for MacOS.

Thank you for this suggestion! It's a pity that jdupes doesn't seem to have preserved the option --time, but otherwise it seems to be more powerful than fdupes.
